# simple javascript for loop not behaving the way I think it should

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
for (var i=0; i<Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function(object){
    alert(Gmaps.map.markers[i]); 
  });
};
```

So, this goes through the loop.  I'm using this with the google maps API, obviously.  Each of the markers on the map has the alert attached to it.  The alert shows `undefined` though.  If I switch it to `alert(Gmaps.map.markers[0]);` or any other applicable number, it shows me Object object, as it should.  If I then call `alert(Gmaps.map.markers[i].id);` or the like, I get the value I'm looking for, but obviously, every marker gives the same alert.

Why is the `i` not being recognized in the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to privatize the i:

```
for (var i=0; i<Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++) {
 (function(i){
  google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function(object){
    alert(Gmaps.map.markers[i]); 
  });
 }(i));
};
```

Comment: that works.  whoa.  I don't claim to be an expert at this stuff, but I've been tinkering in this business for about a year, and the concept of privatizing something never came up.  odd.  thanks!

Comment: loops don't have scope, but functions do. i almost always use .map instead of for if i can. with "Gmaps.map.markers.map(function(mark,i){ ", "Gmaps.map.markers[i]" becomes just "mark", and "i" is automatic and  private.